# Reconstructing a signal from a Nyquist plot

Tags: fft, nyquist, inverse-problem

I have a system which is like a blackbox which has just one input which could be a sinusoidal wave which is a sum of a range of frequencies, now the problem is that I dont have the time-domain output values but the real and imaginary values of a Nyquist plot for the input and the output fft.
Would there be a way to reconstruct the output signal of the blackbox knowing the real and imaginary values of the nyquist plot? or knowing the sampling frequency of the output is the key?

Answer (score 0):

The "Nyquist Plot" is typically the Fourier Transform of the system's impulse response, which would then be the frequency response. The plot starts at frequency $f=0$ and then sweeps out to $f=f_s$ where $f_s$ is the sampling rate, plotting the magnitude and phase for each frequency on a complex plane. The frequency response would be the output divided by the input as a complex value for each given frequency. If the OP really has an FFT of the input and FFT of the output separately, then this isn't a Nyquist Plot but simply plots of the FFT plotted on a complex plane.  To reconstruct the output signal in the time domain, simply take the inverse FFT for each of the complex samples associated with each frequency bin (that have been plotted on a complex plane).